# Generate checksum via Ant not include file name in checksum result

Tags: maven, ant

Using ant checksum https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/checksum.html for generate sha256 checksum

```
<target name="generate_checksum">
    <checksum Algorithm="SHA-256" fileext=".sha256">
        <fileset dir="/home/myusername/temp/checksum">
            <include name="*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </checksum>
</target>
```

Output of checksum file test.jar.sha256 file contain

```
c90fef8607e3ee7686d893d3980b6f21c5f1f138c829acc39ea64d25c8955080
```

Only checksum not contain filename

In Linux command if I use

```
sha256sum test.jar > sha265sums.txt
```

Getting checksum with filename

```
c90fef8607e3ee7686d893d3980b6f21c5f1f138c829acc39ea64d25c8955080  test.jar
```

Any option there in **ant** to include file name as well. Note, file name is unknown, any file contain in a folder which ends with .jar

Or any alternatives in Maven also fine to use.

Comment: The file name is never part of the hash...

Comment: Yes correct, but i need result how it return by "sha256sum test.jar > sha265sums.txt", any option in ant ?

Comment: Ah you mean the format in the resulting txt file... not by Ant that I know...

Comment: there is a 'pattern' tag which I think does what you want: https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/checksum.html

Comment: @roediGERhard it worked with pattern, Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using pattern Attributes result file of checksum we can add file name like below it works. Thanks @roediGERhard

Reference : https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/checksum.html

```
<target name="generate_checksum" pattern="{0} {1}">
  <checksum Algorithm="SHA-256" fileext=".sha256">
    <fileset dir="/home/myusername/temp/checksum">
        <include name="*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
  </checksum>
</target>
```

Result become

```
c90fef8607e3ee7686d893d3980b6f21c5f1f138c829acc39ea64d25c8955080  test.jar
```